# Does a Gold Axe mine faster than a Diamond Axe in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been looking around on a lot of Minecraft websites, and I have seen that Gold tools, as crappy as they are, work faster than Diamond tools on some blocks. Does anyone know if this is actually true? I want to know because I want to make sure, because I am working on a future command on Bedrock Edition for a God Axe that chops faster than any other axe in the game, and also does significant damage to mobs and other players.

Comment: *"on a lot of Minecraft websites"* - don't. There is only [the one](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Axe) to look for, unless you are using mods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, unenchanted Golden Axes are faster than Diamond Axes.

a Diamond Axe chops a block of wood in 0.4 seconds, where a Golden Axe chops a block of wood in 0.25 seconds.

[Gamepedia article detailing chopping speeds](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Axe)

---

### The below relates to pickaxes... as i misread the question!

Yes, on the blocks they can mine, they mine faster.

For instance, it takes 0.95 seconds to mine a redstone block with a Diamond Pickaxe, and 0.65 seconds with a Golden Pickaxe.

[Gamepedia article detailing mining speeds.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pickaxe)

Comment: I have seen that article, but I want to know if a Gold Axe chops trees faster than a Diamond Axe. I have a command in which it gives me a very good Axe, but I am undecided between Gold and Diamond. (/give @s <gold/diamond>_axe 1 0 {ench:[{id:9,lvl:100000},{id:10,lvl:100000},{id:11,lvl:100000},{id:26,lvl:100000},{id:15, lvl:100000},{id:16,lvl:100000},{id:17,lvl:100000},{id:18,lvl:100000}]},{display:{Name:”God Axe”,lore:[“The Best Axe in The World!!!”,”Chops Trees In the Blink of an Eye!!!”,”Also Kills Mobs Fast!”]},{Unbreakable:1},{HideFlags:4}]})

Comment: Axes! not Pickaxes. Ooops. Edited the answer... :). Don't forget to click accept if you feel this does indeed answer your question.

Comment: Hey, don't worry about it. I have misread a lot of questions. I have had to read them over again, to read them the right way.  That happens from time to time!

Comment: The answer is the same in either case.

Comment: I have heard. Also, I have heard that Diamond pickaxes can mine more blocks than Gold pickaxes. Is this true? I am also working on a command to give me a God Pickaxe (/give @s <gold\diamond>_pickaxe 1 0 {ench:[{id:15,lvl:100000},{id:16,lvl:100000},{id:17,lvl:100000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:26,lvl:100000},{display:{Name:”God Pick”,lore:[”THE BEST PICK EVER!!!”,”Fast Miner”,”Lvl 100000 on all Enchants”]},{Unbreakable:1},{HideFlags:4}]}).

Comment: Check the page again... the crux of it that a diamond axe has more durability than all others.

Comment: BTW, Do you have any tips on becoming good at Real Survival Minecraft? RN, I just play Survival like Creative, but with limited resources.

Comment: Comments wouldn't be the best place for that.

Comment: Okay. Maybe you could email me?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct! Though golden axes have lower hp than diamond axes, golden axes have 15% faster mining speed.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed to know for my command!

Comment: @ShadowBlstrTheNinja No problem! Please remember to vote up my answer if you think it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as people have said above, yes, a golden axe is better in terms of speed, but if you are trying to get the most amount of wood possible in a certain about of time in a big cube, the diamond axe would be more efficient because of its better durability.